# How would be society's reactions if scientistis created an hermaphrodite man capable of giving birth?

Tags: biology, society, religion, genetic-engineering, bioengineering

If genetic engineered and/or bioengineering was used to create a man with true hermaphroditism( he would also have male gender identity) who could get pregnant on his own by self fertilization or having sex with an ordinary biological man, how would society react to this and how much would change? If their presence in society become more commonplace over time would people change their perception of gender and gender roles? I believe that most people would then begin to think that males can also get pregnant. By the way it would be the main idea behind their creation.

Transguys in real life already can get pregnant but they were assigned female at birth. However, these bioengineered men would be assigned male at birth.

Could people also become less religious since the bible state that god created man and woman?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be asked on this site. We don't do questions of the form "how would the world/society be different if [one big thing] were changed?"

Comment: There is not one society, but many with many different viewpoints on birthing life and gender roles ♀️♂️, even inside them. You should really ponder on that before asking yourself this kind of question : To which society are you referring to?

Comment: This type of 'what if' question is not a good fit here.  It cannot be answered objectively, and who's to say one answer is any better than another.  Additionally, we don't know about your proposed world and how its people will react - that's up to you - and we don't answer questions about what real-world people would do.  Since there is an existing answer, please post a new question that addresses these issues.

Comment: As for this question's viability on this site, since this is not a sociology and anthropology Q&A site, but a worldbuilding one, topics like "how would this society reacts?" will almost always lead to the not very helpful answer "[how you want them to (re)act for your story](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)". Building a fictional world isn't solely defined by what the real-world is, but what you want it to be ✏️

Comment: Arnold Schwarzenegger already did this in the 1994 feature length documentary [*Junior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_(1994_film)). As far as I remember, the reaction of society was mild amusement.

Comment: (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question. (b) This question violates a number of rules found in the [tour] and [help], please read them carefully. (c) Questions that ask how the whole world would change due to one small change are always closed. (d) Your idea would only work if your engineerierd people could overcome genetic problems due to incest. (e) For a passable solution to your problem, read the *[Orthogonal Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_(series))* by Greg Egan. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... (f) Finally, this really isn't a worldbuilding question at all. It's a storybuilding quesiton. You're asking how people would react - what choices they'd make - and that's strictly prohibited in the [help/on-topic]. You've already done your worldbuilding: you rationalized the creation of a being that could be used to challenge culture and belief. Now it's up to you to write the story about that challenge. But that's not what we do here.

Answer (score 3):

### Crimes against nature

Since you include the bit about Judeo-Christian religion, I'll focus on that.

Like with anything else, the Christian reaction would be varied. The very liberal denominations would probably just ignore it and/or lampshade things with "love is love", etc. The very conservative/fundamentalist denominations would probably call for the "destruction" of the "freaks".

As for the middle of the bell curve, it would not change anything. The hermaphrodites would be artificially created from the get-go, so it has no bearing on transgenderism. Insofar as there *are* natural hermaphrodites, they are freaks of nature, the results of sin's perverting effects on reality.

Not only would it not contradict the Bible, it would actually serve to prove the opposite. The very fact that the hermaphrodites have to be *artificially* created proves that humans are naturally male and female.

Relative to the hermaphrodites themselves, I imagine that most non-hyper-liberal Christians' reaction would be pity that they have to live with such twisted bodies, depending on how much all the genetic tinkering messes with their health.